# copy data from one worksheet to another

Tags: excel

I want to copy data from one worksheet to another. I .I have a big data spreadsheet and i want to copy only some data(depending on what data is given in 1st column of sheet2). I want to copy the data only for the 234 entries in sheet2. But if I run this code then it doesn't stop.Why? What is wrong with the code?

```
Sub transferdata()
Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastrow1 As Long, lastrow2 As Long
Dim Mat As Variant

lastrow1 = Workbooks("Database").Sheets("DataBase").Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow1
Mat = Workbooks("Database").Sheets("DataBase").Cells(i, "K").Value

lastrow2 = Workbooks("Test").Sheets("TransferData").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For j = 2 To lastrow2

If Workbooks("Test").Sheets("TransferData").Cells(j, "A").Value = Mat Then
Workbooks("Database").Sheets("DataBase").Activate
Workbooks("Database").Sheets("DataBase").Cells(i, "L").Copy
Workbooks("Test").Sheets("TransferData").Activate
Workbooks("Test").Sheets("TransferData").Cells(j, "B").Select
Workbooks("Test").Sheets("TransferData").PasteSpecial
End If

Next j
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Please be more specific, what is your Question, what is the expected behaviour and what is this code snippet actually doing?

Comment: Wow, can't imagine how you got this kind of code. o_O Anyway, I try to rephrase what you want to achieve: Col A in Sheet2 has entries. You want to find the entry in the Database-Sheet and copy something (a range? A value?) from there to Sheet2 (where exaxtly?)? Is that correct? What exactly do you want to copy?

Comment: Yes I want to find the entry in Database copy the other information(columns) related to the entry in sheet2

Comment: @bkausbk - This code is not generating output. I want to find a code which copies my data from database sheet to sheet2 (I have one column already present in sheet2 and these entries are serial numbers). So I have to find the serial numbers in Database sheet and then copy the other details(columns) for the respective serial number.

Comment: I'm getting runtime error '9'  Subscript out of range for the line below.why?

>lastrow1 = Workbooks("Database").Sheets("DataBase").Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row